# Debug Blazor Server in VSCode

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, blazor-server-side

launch.json:

```
   "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "msedge",                    
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",           
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",                   
            // "serverReadyAction": {
            //     "action": "openExternally",
            //     "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            // },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
                "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:5000"
            },
            "sourceMaps": true,                            
            //"url": "http://localhost:5000",
            // If you have changed the default port / launch URL make sure to update the expectation below    
            //"inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
        },    
        {    
                "name": ".NET Core Attach",
                "type": "coreclr",
                "request": "attach",
                "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
            
        ]
```

and tasks.json:

```
 "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "dotnet",
            //"group": "build",            
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "run",                          
                "${workspaceFolder}/BlazorStore9.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],                 
            // "presentation": {
            //     // Reveal the output only if unrecognized errors occur.
            //     "reveal": "silent"
            // },
            // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "options": {"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"}
        }
    ]
```

This only launches site for browsing but not debug, How to correct these files for debug?

Answer (score 1):

I removed "request": "launch", from launch.json and debug works.